# Javascript: how ++ operator work?

Tags: javascript, operators

I am currently converting a function from javascript to another language. I have little experience with javascript.
I am currently with a doubt regarding the following piece of code:

```
msi = pii.charCodeAt(Y++) << 24 | pii.charCodeAt(Y++) << 16
```

The Y++ will increase the variable, every time that it is called (and globally change the variable value)?
Or it is equivalent to just increate a unit, like:

```
Y+1
```

Regrads

Comment: The `++` operator in JavaScript works the same way it works in all C-family languages. If it's *before* the variable, it increments the variable first and the value is the new incremented value. If it's *after* the variable, the value of the expression is the *pre-increment* value, but the variable is incremented afterwards.

Comment: And it is not like `Y+1`... `Y+1` will evaluate the incremented value but the value of `Y` is unaffected...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`Y++` will increase the value of Y by one, as used in an expression it provides the original (non-incremented) value of Y. You should note however that your code increments Y twice.

Comment: And the first time it will be Y and the second time it will be Y+1.

Comment: Thank you for the explanation :)

Answer (score 1):

```
var Y = 1;
var Z = Y++; // Z will be 1 and Y will be 2 !!! after this line is executed
```

This is **not** specific for javascript.

Answer (score 0):

The increment operators are somewhat different than your ordinary increments such as `Y = Y+1`... The post and pre increment operators in JavaScript work same as in C, C++, Java and many other. How do they work actually here is a brief intro:

`Z = Y++` means store value of `Y` to `Z` and then increment value of `Y` by 1.

whereas

`Z = ++Y` means increment value of `Y` by 1 and afterwards store it to `Z` (i.e. the updated value)